# problem with npm updates and peer dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I've taken over an angular project a former colleague. Unfortunately, I'm not very experienced in angular and npm. When I push a new version of the project, a gitlab runner creates a new docker image of it. While the project build and runs smoothly, I can see a lot of warnings in Gitlab, mainly  that it gives a lot of warnings, mainly due to deprecated packages. I wanted to do something against that and updated angular and some of the packages. Here is what 'npm outdated' gives at the moment:

```
Package                            Current   Wanted  Latest  Location                                        Depended by
@angular-devkit/build-angular       12.0.5   12.0.5  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
@angular-devkit/core                12.0.5   12.1.1  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular-devkit/core
@angular-devkit/schematics          12.0.5   12.1.1  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics
@angular/animations                 12.0.5   12.0.5  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/animations
@angular/cli                        12.0.5   12.0.5  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/cli
@angular/common                     12.0.5   12.0.5  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/common
@angular/compiler                   12.0.5   12.0.5  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/compiler
@angular/compiler-cli               12.0.5   12.0.5  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
@angular/core                       12.0.5   12.0.5  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/core
@angular/elements                   12.0.5   12.1.1  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/elements
@angular/forms                      12.0.5   12.0.5  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/forms
@angular/language-service           12.0.5   12.0.5  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/language-service
@angular/localize                   12.0.5   12.1.1  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/localize
@angular/platform-browser           12.0.5   12.0.5  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   12.0.5   12.0.5  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
@angular/router                     12.0.5   12.0.5  12.1.1  node_modules/@angular/router
@schematics/angular                 10.2.3   10.2.3  12.1.1  node_modules/@schematics/angular
@types/jasmine                      3.6.11   3.6.11   3.7.7  node_modules/@types/jasmine
@types/node                        14.17.4  14.17.4  16.0.0  node_modules/@types/node
chart.js                             2.9.4    2.9.4   3.4.1  node_modules/chart.js
core-js                             3.15.1   3.15.2  3.15.2  node_modules/core-js
fs-extra                             9.1.0    9.1.0  10.0.0  node_modules/fs-extra
jasmine-core                         3.6.0    3.6.0   3.8.0  node_modules/jasmine-core
jasmine-spec-reporter                5.0.2    5.0.2   7.0.0  node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter
prettier                             2.2.1    2.2.1   2.3.2  node_modules/prettier
rxjs                                 6.6.7    6.6.7   7.1.0  node_modules/rxjs
ts-node                             8.10.2   8.10.2  10.0.0  node_modules/ts-node
typescript                           4.2.4    4.2.4   4.3.5  node_modules/typescript
```

However, I get a lot of errors like this one, when I try 'npm update angular-oauth2-oidc-jwks':

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: simplecomp@0.3.6
npm ERR! Found: tslib@2.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/tslib
npm ERR!   tslib@"^2.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer tslib@"^1.10.0" from angular-oauth2-oidc-jwks@9.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc-jwks
npm ERR!   angular-oauth2-oidc-jwks@"^9.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I've read through some documentation and different things I found on google, but I still don't really get what I should do know. I do know that the problem arises from the dependencies that are written into package.json. When I search for "tslib" in the package.json, there is one entry '"tslib": "^2.0.0",' under 'dependencies'. This means that my projet (thinks it) needs exactly version 2.0.0 of tslib, right? But the package I wanted to update wants a version. Do I understand that correctly?

I don't know what to do about that. Can somebody try to walk me through? Is there one solution for all such conflicts or do I have to solve each dependency conflict in a different way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. I tried  :

reinstall angular cli

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

#Clear Cache:

npm cache clean --force

npm cache verify

#Install Angular CLI:

npm install -g @angular/cli
```